# RegisterController.php create() returns 419 status error

Tags: php, rest, jwt, postman, laravel-5.5

When I am running my `create()` to create a user from my `RegisterController` it is returning me a `419` error. I've been trying to set up auth tokens using JWT, it's not fully completed yet and I am trying to set up my register controller so I can register a user and login.

**NOTE:** when I am running my register end point it is generating me a token (which I don't know why)

I am using `laravel 5.5`

and

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.1"
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Consumer;
//use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;


    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //     $this->middleware('guest');
    // }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'con_fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'con_lname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:consumers',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Consumer::create([
            'con_fname' => $data['con_fname'],
            'con_lname' => $data['con_lname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'con_cover_photo' => null,
            'con_profile_pic' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;



Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::resource('business', 'BusinessController');
Route::resource('consumer', 'ConsumerController');
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@create');

Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

**END POINT (run in postman)**

```
http://localhost:8000/register
```

**body of my post man endpoint**

```
{
    "email": "user1@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "password_confirmation": "password",
    "con_fname": "john",
    "con_lname": "doe"
}
```